# Move function contents to external file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, canvas

I'm using kinetic.js with HTML5 canvas. I've created a layer with a shape like so:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var tile = new Kinetic.Shape({
  sceneFunc: function(context) {
    context.fillStyle="rgb(255,255,255)";
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(256,197);
    context.lineTo(177,241);
    context.bezierCurveTo(172,237,167,232,162,228);
    context.lineTo(0,100);
    context.fill();
  }
});
layer.add(tile);
```

Now I need to move everything within the `sceneFunc` to an external file. There are going to be lots of these files with different shapes in. Then I need to be able to load the external file and execute the code within the `sceneFunc`. Such as:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var tile = new Kinetic.Shape({
  sceneFunc: function(context) {
    //call and execute shape code here
  }
});
layer.add(tile);
```

with the following code in a separate file:

```
context.fillStyle="rgb(255,255,255)";
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(256,197);
context.lineTo(177,241);
context.bezierCurveTo(172,237,167,232,162,228);
context.lineTo(0,100);
context.fill();
```

Is there a way of doing this? I know I can create a script tag of the external file, but that will execute the code outside of the `sceneFunc` function. The same would be true of using an ajax call with `XMLHttpRequest` and parsing it with `eval();`

How do I read the code from the external file, then execute it in the correct place?!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you're trying to do, but you could do something like this:

Create an array of shape functions

```
var shapes=[];
```

then in the small files have something like

```
shapes.push(function(context){
  context.fillStyle="rgb(255,255,255)";
  // shape drawing code here
});
```

use `<script>` tags to load the small files after the array declaration, then in your `sceneFunc` do something like

```
shapes.forEach(function(shape) {
  shape(context);
});
```

You could do something similar with XHR and eval (and in that case you could programmatically add the "shapes.push" stuff instead of having it in the small files), but you would need to asynchronously invoke the shape creation only when all the shapes have loaded.

Comment: Interesting. If possible, I've been trying to avoid the script tag creation. Would you be able to show an example of your other suggestion using XHR and eval? Is it unsafe to use eval?

Comment: Also, when I create the script tag using JS and append it to the doc head, the shapes array isn't filled until after I ask to look inside it. So I end up looking at an empty array...

Comment: yeah, if you're injecting the scripts programmatically, you'll need to do a similar asynchronous thing, or maybe also inject the script that invokes Kinetic.js *after* you inject the others. Sorry, don't have time right now to create an example using XHR, but what I had in mind was firing off asynchronous requests using XHR (or jquery or other XHR wrapper), keeping track of how many are active, and in the callback for the requests check if it's the last one, and if so invoke the Kinetic stuff. eval is safe if you have complete control of all the scripts, which you do in this case.